# Why am I getting EITHER an UnboundLocalError in reference to pylab.legend, OR a No Such File error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

Ok, I know there are a LOT of questions about UnboundLocalError(s). I've read them, and have attempted to solve my issue, but do not think my error *directly* stems from a global/local variable issue in the same way as other questions.

My actual project is something else, but I can get the same error using some basic code I referenced in a past question. It's also a lot shorter, so I think it might be easier to just reference this code again. It's a modification of code in Bird, Klein, & Loper's "Natural Language Processing with Python".

```
import os, re, csv, string, operator
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
dir = '/Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/hearings/'

corpus_root = dir
hearings = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, ".txt")

cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
     (target, fileid[:3])
     for fileid in hearings.fileids()
     if os.path.getsize(fileid) > 0 #to avoid empty files
     for w in hearings.words(fileid)
     for target in ['reform']
     if w.lower().startswith(target))
cfd.plot()
```

EDIT: Including more of the console output to answer below question about the completeness of the traceback. I opened a fresh editor, ran the code above, and did nothing else.

Here is the traceback of the error:

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
with pylab-backend set to: qt
Type '?' for more information.

In[1]: %run /Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/python_code/hearings_ingest.py

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    181             else:
    182                 filename = fname
--> 183             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/python_code/hearings_ingest.py in <module>()
     19      for target in ['reform']
     20      if w.lower().startswith(target))
---> 21 cfd.plot()
     22 
     23 

/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1791             pylab.plot(freqs, *args, **kwargs)
   1792 
-> 1793         pylab.legend(loc=legend_loc)
   1794         pylab.grid(True, color="silver")
   1795         pylab.xticks(range(len(samples)), [unicode(s) for s in samples], rotation=90)

   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'legend_loc' referenced before assignment

In[2]:
```

The last call looks, to my inexperience eye, like something about building the legend for the graph is going awry. But moving backwards, there is also a problem with the files (again, I think).

If I call `hearings.fileids()` in this case, I get `[]` returned.

HOWEVER. If I change the file extensions to .* in the hearings= code, as follows

```
hearings = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, ".*")
```

and run everything again, I now get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '105Congress/105House/CHRG-105hhrg37099.txt'
```

EDIT: Including more of the console output to answer below question about the completeness of the traceback. I opened a fresh editor, ran the code above, and did nothing else.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
with pylab-backend set to: qt
Type '?' for more information.

In[1]: %run /Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/python_code/hearings_ingest.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    181             else:
    182                 filename = fname
--> 183             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/python_code/hearings_ingest.py in <module>()
     14 cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
     15      (target, fileid[:3])
---> 16      for fileid in hearings.fileids()
     17      if os.path.getsize(fileid) > 0 #to avoid empty files
     18      for w in hearings.words(fileid)

/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.pyc in __init__(self, cond_samples)
   1727         defaultdict.__init__(self, FreqDist)
   1728         if cond_samples:
-> 1729             for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:
   1730                 self[cond].inc(sample)
   1731 

/Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/python_code/hearings_ingest.py in <genexpr>((fileid,))
     15      (target, fileid[:3])
     16      for fileid in hearings.fileids()
---> 17      if os.path.getsize(fileid) > 0 #to avoid empty files
     18      for w in hearings.words(fileid)
     19      for target in ['reform']

/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc in getsize(filename)
     47 def getsize(filename):
     48     """Return the size of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
---> 49     return os.stat(filename).st_size
     50 
     51 

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '105Congress/105House/CHRG-105hhrg37099.txt'

In[2]:
```

In this case, when I call `hearings.fileids()` I get returned the full list of ~30K filenames I'm attempting to process. Indeed, I can call

```
hearings.words('105Congress/105House/CHRG-105hhrg37099.txt')
```

and get back the initial contents of the file -- the very file that the error says does not exist.

Details: 
Python 2.7 
Editor(s): I've tried this in multiple editors including Canopy 1.1.0, emacs 24.3 (my standard editor), command line, etc. 
Mac OSX 10.9.1 (also run under Crunchbang Linux 11, through parallels).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I don't like about IPython. *Lengthy trackbacks*.

Comment: Is that first traceback right? I don't think so. Secondly, have you ensured `/Users/me/Dropbox/testimony/hearings/` actually has `.txt` files in it?

Comment: Hah, yeah, I'd agree. But yes, that was copied and pasted directly from my editor. Is there a better way to show the error that would be more clearly related to the code? I simply ran the code using Canopy's "run highlighted code" command, and then copied out the traceback that results. If it helps, it's exactly the same when I do it using ipython in emacs. 

And yeah, the folders all have several thousand files apiece. I can post a screenshot of that if you want confirmation.

Comment: Is that, the first one, the complete traceback? It's starting at line 183, unlike the second one which starts at 11.

Comment: It's the full and complete traceback in both cases. I don't know that it helps, but I edited the question to include the _console_ information around the traceback to illustrate that nothing except running the code in the question was done.

Comment: Thanks to Bleeding for the initial help. Still stuck, though!

Comment: What nltk version you using? I suspect a bug in nltk.

Comment: Hey, thanks again! Looks like it's running 2.0.4.